# PyList_SetItem vs. PyList_SETITEM

Tags: python, python-c-extension

From what I can tell, the difference between PyList_SetItem and PyList_SETITEM is that PyList_SetItem will lower the reference count of the list item it overwrites and PyList_SETITEM does not.

Is there any reason why I shouldn't just use PyList_SetItem all the time? Or would I get into trouble if I used PyList_SetItem to initialize an index position in a list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`PyList_SET_ITEM` is an unsafe macro that basically sticks an object into the list's internal pointer array without any bound checks. If anything non-`NULL` is in the `i`th position of the list, a reference leak will occur. `PyList_SET_ITEM` steals the reference to the object you put in the list. `PyList_SetItem` also steals the reference, but it checks bounds and decrefs anything which may be in the `i`th position. The rule-of-thumb is use `PyList_SET_ITEM` to initialize lists you've just created and `PyList_SetItem` otherwise. It's also completely safe to use `PyList_SetItem` everywhere; `PyList_SET_ITEM` is basically a speed hack.

Comment: But will I get into any sort of trouble if I use PyList_SetItem *all* the time and *never* use PyList_SETITEM?

Comment: Absolutely not. In fact, that's probably the safest way. `PyList_SET_ITEM` is mostly a speed hack.

Comment: Thanks - and thanks for adding the clarifying last line to your original answer.